# Accessing input value on click or enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simply return a value entered into an input field.

I want to use jQuery to access the value, store to a variable, and return it from a called function.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js">      </script>
    <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript" src = "Database.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
          <input type ="text" id="input"/></br>
          <input type="button" id="insert"/>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var toSubmit = function() {
  var text = $("#input").val();
  return text;
};

var enterPressed = function() {
  $('#input').keyup(function(button) {
    if(button.keyCode==13) {
      toSubmit();
    }
  };

function enterPressed();

});
```

I haven't worked on the functionality of the button included, please ignore that.

When I run this in Chrome's Javascript console I get "Unexpected token function for line 15. Am I incorrectly calling the function?

All I want the program to do is to return the value of the input box as soon as the user presses enter.

**Update**

HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var toSubmit = function() {
  var text = $("#input").val();
  return text;
};

var enterPressed = function() {
  $('#input').keyup(function(button) {
    if(button.keyCode==13) {
      toSubmit();
    }
  });
};

enterPressed();

});
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var values = [];

var toSubmit = function() {
  var text = $("#input").val();
  values.push(text);
  console.log(values);
  return false;
};

var formSubmit = function(e) {
  $('#form').submit(toSubmit);
};

});
```

Comment: First of all, change this `function enterPressed();` to this `enterPressed();`. This is the error origin. And close the `enterPressed` function with `}`, its missing.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown -- Post that as an answer.

Comment: @tymeJV I wasn't sure if that was the real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DontVoteMeDown said in the comments, `function enterPressed();` is a syntax error and you forgot to close `enterPressed`. You also forgot to close the `keyup` with `});`. I've corrected the errors in this code:

**EDIT:** Changed to `event.which` rather than `event.keyCode` ([`which` normalizes `keyCode` and `charCode`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toSubmit = function() {
    var text = $("#input").val();
    return text;
  };

  var enterPressed = function() {
    $('#input').keyup(function(event) {
      if(event.which == 13) {
        toSubmit();
      }
    });
  };

  enterPressed();

});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/D66Zw/1/

**UPDATE:**

If you can, it would be better if you just listened for a form's `submit` event. That way you can call `toSubmit` and it will handle the enter key press and the submit button. Here is how you could do that:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toSubmit = function(e) {
     var text = $("#input").val();

     // do whatever you want to do with 'text' variable here

     // stop form from submitting
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
  };

  var formSubmit = function() {
      $('#form').submit(toSubmit);
  };

  // call this when you want to bind the submit handler
  formSubmit();

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <input type ="text" id="input"/><br />
    <input type="submit" id="insert"/>
</form>
```

New jsFiddle example, clicking the submit button and pressing enter works: http://jsfiddle.net/D66Zw/2/

**Pushing value to array**

Before the `toSubmit` function, create the array:

```
var list = [];
```

In the `toSubmit` function:

```
// push text to array
list.push(text);

// output array in console
console.log(list);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D66Zw/4/ (open up the console to see the array every time enter is pressed)

Comment: @Nathan I've made my code identical to yours, and am getting no errors, but the `values` isn't printing to the console. Am I calling my Javascript source too early in my HTML maybe? I saw that your JSFiddle example worked...

See my updated code above.

Comment: I just wonder why you guys insist to create a function to bind the event, if it will be called just once AND it is called right after its declaration.

Comment: @matt81m With `document.ready` you can place it anywhere on the page (it won't be called until the DOM is ready). I changed it to `list` after I saved the edit because I noticed in your comment you said an array named `list`. Is the global array created outside of `toSubmit`? Are you trying to use `list` outside of the `document.ready`? The `list` array can only be used within `document.ready` unless it is declared outside of it.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I don't really care about keeping it in a function (I personally wouldn't put it in its own function either, but I guess matt81m wants it like that so it can binded later on in the script).

Comment: @Nathan I forgot to call `formSubmit()` at the end. It appears to be working now. Can you explain why the `return false;` is needed at the end of the function `toSubmit`?

Comment: @matt81m It stops the default behavior, which is the form submitting normally.

Comment: But there is no sense on calling the function to bind it later.. but, nevermind. Remember to use `preventDefault()` together with `return false` to stop form submission.

Comment: @Nathan What is a "normal" form submission?

Comment: @matt81m The form submitting to the server and the page reloading. The comment form on here submits with ajax but if they didn't stop the form from submitting, the entire page would reload every time you post a comment. You're not really submitting any data, so it needs to be stopped from submitting or the page will reload.

Comment: @matt81m Yup, no problem. Please click the green checkmark next to my answer to accept it if it answers your question.